# Using AWS Storages Services (EBS or EFS or S3) as Volumes or Mount Binds with Stanalone Docker Containers not ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, docker-swarm, amazon-efs

I have self-managed AWS Cluster over which I am looking to run Docker Containers.
(At present, ECS and EKS are not in my scope though in future they might... but I need focus on present requirement).

I got to add persistence to few containers by attaching AWS efs/ebs/s3fs storages (as appropriate for the use case). AWS has addressed [this use case](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/amazon-ecs-and-docker-volume-drivers-amazon-efs/) through a lengthy and verbose blog which takes ECS in to picture. Like said my requirement is simple and this article seems to do many things like cloudFormaton etc etc..

Will appreciate if anyone can simplify this a provide the bare bones step I need to follow.

1) I installed the ebs/efs/s3fs drivers -

```
 docker plugin install --grant-all-permissions rexray/ebs
```

and so on for efs and s3fs too.  s3fs installation ran into trouble.

> Error response from daemon: dial unix
>   /run/docker/plugins/b0b9c534158e73cb07011350887501fe5fd071585af540c2264de760f8e2c0d9/rexray.sock:
>   connect: no such file or directory

But this is not my problem for the moment unless someone wants to volunteer on solving this issue.

**Where I am struck is -** what are the next steps to create volumes or directly mount them at run time to containers as volumes or mount binds (is this supported? or just volumes).

Comment: Still need help on this?

Comment: @2ps, help will be greatly appreciated. The problem is stil unresolved at my end.

Answer (score 1):

here are the steps for ec2-based ecs services (since fargate instances do not support docker volumes as of today):

1. Update your instance role to [include the following permissions](https://rexray.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/storage-providers/aws/#troubleshooting):

   ```
   ec2:AttachVolume
   ec2:CreateVolume
   ec2:CreateSnapshot
   ec2:CreateTags
   ec2:DeleteVolume
   ec2:DeleteSnapshot
   ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones
   ec2:DescribeInstances
   ec2:DescribeVolumes
   ec2:DescribeVolumeAttribute
   ec2:DescribeVolumeStatus
   ec2:DescribeSnapshots
   ec2:CopySnapshot
   ec2:DescribeSnapshotAttribute
   ec2:DetachVolume
   ec2:ModifySnapshotAttribute
   ec2:ModifyVolumeAttribute
   ec2:DescribeTags
   ```

   this should be for all resources in the policy.  n.b, the createVolume and deleteVolume permissions can be omitted if you don't want to use autoProvision.
2. Install rexray on the instance (you've already done this)
3. If you're not using autoprovision, provision your volume and make sure there is a `Name` tag matching the name of the volume that you want to use in your service definition.  In the example below, we set this value to `rexray-vol`.
4. Update your task definition to include the necessary values for the volume to be mounted as a docker container.  Here is an example:

   ```
   "volumes": [{
       "name": "rexray-vol",
       "dockerVolumeConfiguration": {
           "autoprovision": true,
           "scope": "shared",
           "driver": "rexray/ebs",
           "driverOpts": {
               "volumetype": "gp2",
               "size": "5"
           }
       }
   }]
   ```
5. Update the task definition's container definition to refer your swanky ebs volume:

   ```
   "mountPoints": [
           {
               "containerPath": "/var/lib/mysql",
               "sourceVolume": "rexray-vol"
           }
       ],
   ```

Comment: will give it a try